# ipod classic is not listed under source list in iTune after restore

Tags: ipod

After connect to usb, winXP can open itunes but there is no device on left bar.

I tried re-install iTunes. Reboot iPod, disable anti-virus daemon etc etc, still no go.

Anything else I can do?

Comment: Faulty cable? Faulty USB port? Will the iPod mount on another computer?

Comment: Tried a second winXP PC. Same. iPod is treated as a mobile disk. iTunes is revived but there is no iPod listed at all. If open the disk from "my computer", there are 3 folders: Calendars, Contacts, Notes. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's Knowledgebase suggests a multi-step process for troubleshooting this issue.

> 1. Try the [iPod troubleshooting assistant](http://www.apple.com/support/ipod/five_rs/): If you have not already done so, try the steps in the iPod Troubleshooting Assistant
>      (choose your iPod model from the list).
>
> If the issue remains after following your iPod's troubleshooting
>   assistant, follow the steps below to continue troubleshooting your
>   issue.
>
> 1. Restart the iPod Service
> 2. Restart the Apple Mobile Device Service
> 3. Empty your Temp directory and restart
> 4. Verify that the Apple Mobile Device USB Driver is installed
> 5. Change your iPod's drive letter
> 6. Remove and reinstall iTunes
> 7. Disable conflicting System Services and Startup Items

Apple's [iPod: Appears in Windows but not in iTunes](http://iPod%3a%20Appears%20in%20Windows%20but%20not%20in%20iTunes) contains more details about these steps.

Comment: I read and followed that. Only, I can't find "Apple Mobile Device USB Driver" from the hardware manager. But I have "iPod device" under "disk" section. I tried to update its driver to ipod driver according to the assistant, but when "install from disk", I can't see iPod. That's when I stop..